# Seleccionar elementos ignorando otros con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo esta estructura `HTML`.

```js
var subMenuElementos = $('#menu nav ul li a');
subMenuElementos.removeAttr('href');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

El problema es que no estoy seleccionando correctamente las etiquetas `<a>`que quiero.

¿Cuál sería la manera correcta de seleccionarlas?

Comment: ¿Cuáles quieres, todas las que están en: `<div id="menu">`?

Comment: Quiero quitar el href de las que dices `Quiero quitar su href`. Quiero conservar los demás.

Comment: ¿Cuáles demás? O sea, ¿tú quieres quitar el `href` de todas las `<a>` muestras en el código?

Answer (score 1):

Está realizando mal la selección de elementos debería decirle a `JQuery` que no tome los a que estén dentro de la clase `submenú`, esto se puede lograr con [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) `$("#menu a").not(".sub-menu a");` seleccionamos todas las etiquetas `a` de `#menu` pero `not` las que están dentro de la clase `.sub-menu`

```js
$(function() {
    var subMenuElementos = $("#menu a").not(".sub-menu a");
    $(subMenuElementos).removeAttr('href');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira este código, haciendo uso de `querySelectorAll`.

Aquí `var eSet = document.getElementById('menu').querySelectorAll('a');` seleccionas todos los `<a>` dentro del elemento cuyo id es `menu`, y los recorres para quitarle el atributo.

### ► Javascript puro

```js
function cambiarLinks() {

  var eSet = document.getElementById('menu').querySelectorAll('a');
  var i = eSet.length;

  while (i--) {
  var url=eSet[i].href;
    eSet[i].removeAttribute('href');
    console.log(url + ' ha sido quitado');
  }
  
}
window.onload = cambiarLinks;
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

---

### ► jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  var eSet = $('#menu').find('a');
  var i = eSet.length;

  while (i--) {
    var url = eSet[i].href;
    eSet[i].removeAttribute('href');
    console.log(url + ' ha sido quitado');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción seria usar el [selector de hijos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) indicando hasta el nivel deseado:

```
#menu > nav > ul > li > a
```

Ejemplo:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#menu > nav > ul > li > a").removeAttr('href');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero conservar su href</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://google.com">Quiero quitar su href</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```